# Modularity of Euler $q$-series.

Tags: number-theory, modular-forms, q-series, dedekind-eta-function

The Dedekind $\eta$ function is defined as a function on the upper half space $\mathbb{H}$ as
$$\eta(\tau) = e^{\frac{\pi i \tau}{12}}\prod_{n>0}(1-e^{2\pi i n\tau})$$
or, using the circular variable $q=e^{2\pi i \tau}$, as the following $q$-series
$$\eta(q) = q^{\frac{1}{24}}\prod_{n>0}(1-q^n).$$
It is well know that the Dedekind $\eta$ function satisfies a modular property very similar to the one satisfied by a weight $1/2$ modular form, i.e.
$$\eta\left(\dfrac{a\tau+b}{c\tau+d}\right) = c(a,b,c,d)(c\tau+d)^{1/2}\eta(\tau)$$
essentially given by the fact the the $24^{\mathrm{th}}$-power of $\eta$ is a modular form of weight $12$. What I am interested in is the function
$$\phi(q):=q^{-\frac{1}{24}}\eta(q) = \prod_{n>0}(1-q^n)$$
known as the Euler function or Euler $q$-series.
The question is: does $\phi$ satisfies any kind of modular property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we had $\phi \in M_k(\Gamma, \chi)$ for some half-integer $k \in \frac{1}{2} \Bbb Z$ and congruence subgroup $\Gamma$ and a character $\chi$ of finite order on it, then $q(z)^{-1 / 24}$ would be modular as well (in $M_{k - 1/2}(\Gamma, \chi / c)$), which cannot happen. Indeed, since $\chi / c$ has finite order ($\chi$ has order 24), then by raising to a sufficiently large power (some multiple of 24), we get that
$$f : z \mapsto e^{2 \pi i d z} \in M_w(\Gamma)$$
for some integers $w, d \in \Bbb Z$.

Take some $N > 1$ so that $\gamma := \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1  \\ N & 0 \end{pmatrix} \in \Gamma$.
Then
$$f(\gamma z) = f\left( \frac{-1}{N z} \right)
= z^w f(z) \iff
\exp(-2 \pi i d / (N z)) = z^w \exp( 2 \pi i d z )
$$
for all $z \in \Bbb H$.
But then raising to the power $z$ would give that $z \mapsto \exp( z w \log(z) + 2 \pi i d z)$ is constant, which it isn't.

Comment: Note: $\chi$ is only a character for the metaplectic cover, apparently, but anyway, it takes values in the group of 24-th roots of unity which is enough for my argument to run.

Comment: Also at the very end, it should read $2 \pi i d \cdot z^2$, not $2 \pi i d z$.